# Arc Touch mouse scroll stops working

Tags: mouse, hardware-failure

I am using Microsoft Arc Touch mouse. It has a LED battery indicator, which has to *blink* green or red, based on the battery percentage.

My mouse recently started to show the red light (*not blinking*). I tried to change the batteries, but nothing changed.

**The mouse wheel (touch scroller) isn't working.**
EDIT: **The mouse stopped working at all. Just that red light shines well.**
EDIT 2: **Mouse working again except scroll. Red light still shining.**
EDIT 3: **Mouse stopped working again, this time BlueTrack and red light shines.**

---

**Model number: 1428 or 1496** (both written on the package)
[**Product website**](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/mice/arc-touch-mouse/rvf-00052#techspecs-connect)
[**Product guide PDF**](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/E/B/AEB70318-6FE3-48C7-863B-5BFB3BED1FD4/PG_Microsoft-Product-Guide.pdf)

Any ideas?

---

I believe it's a hardware issue. I have to buy a new one.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser Tomas... it may result useful to [edit] your question adding, for example, the model number of your mouse and maybe the link to the manual...

Comment: It seems that there exist may different model with different technologies... add the model even because the [red/green blinking](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052281/accessories-what-do-the-battery-lights-mean-on-my-mouse) may have different reasons/solutions. If bluetooth, e.g., it can be needed a new [pairing procedure](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/arc-touch-mousesurface-edition/dd80c8ea-0177-4b0a-8914-ddcb8aace3d6): _"After several days, I removed it from bluetooth and re-paired it."_

Comment: @Hastur added model number and link to the manual. I have found no information about the LED in product manual.

Comment: @Hastur red/green blinking is not this case, but it has something to do with pairing. My mouse is also not a Surface Edition, so no Bluetooth, but a transceiver. Just note that I have tried 3 different pairs of AAA LR03 batteries (new) and recently, the BlueTrack light stopped working, too. Tried on both Windows 10 and macOS. On Windows, I have reinstalled the drivers as well.

Comment: Did you try to change the port in which you plug the transceiver? ... Check even if the batteries after you remove from the mouse are still working (a short circuit can deplete them). If you have time try to boot from a USB pen with a fresh _untouched_ OS,  e.g. Linux, to check if the mouse works... Good Luck

Comment: okay, tried untouched OS on different computer. meanwhile, the mouse isn't turning on again...

Comment: I will try another new batteries